# Magento 2 - php fatal error class not found

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, php, fatal-error, class

Whatever I try to run on my SSH-Server it displays the same error:

```
$ php bin/magento cron:install [--force]
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'Magento\Setup\Mvc\Bootstrap\InitParamListener' not found in /var/www/vhosts/myurl.de/httpdocs/neu/setup/config/application.config.php:29
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/vhosts/myurl.de/httpdocs/neu/vendor/magento/framework/Console/Cli.php(72): require()
#1 /var/www/vhosts/myurl.de/httpdocs/neu/bin/magento(22): Magento\Framework\Console\Cli->__construct('Magento CLI')
#2 {main}
  thrown in /var/www/vhosts/myurl.de/httpdocs/neu/setup/config/application.config.php on line 29
```

I already tried to check the PHP files but I am a beginner at PHP...
Does someone know a solution?

Comment: What you are trying to do? Means what you are perform?

Comment: I want to run this: bin/magento cron:install [--force]

Comment: Looks like the file could be missing, check if it exists. If it doesn't replace it.